# App crash on windows 10 mobile

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, uwp

This exception occurs when i try to load my app on my device (lumia 950).

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in Template10Library.DLL but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

**The environment**: I'm using Template10 as a git submodule in my project instead of as a nuget package. I also have 2 other 'Class Library' projects and 1 'Windows Runtime Component' projects in my solution that my app depends on.

I'm a bit out of my depth here, I'm pretty new to app development and I have no clear understanding on the particulars of the windows build/deploy/runtime environment so I don't really know where to start.

I know you probably require more information in order to help me, so just ask and I'll try to get back to you.

**Edit:**

I added the following code in my app so that it ran before I got the exception above.

```
try
{
    var assm = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("System.Threading"));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
}
```

By pausing the debugger at `var assm ...` I got the following information from the loaded assembly:

> Fullname: "System.Threading, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
>
> ImageRuntimeVersion: "v4.0.30319"
>
> Location: "C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.THREADING.NI.DLL"

So what does this mean? That my phone have older versions of system dll's? But why does my app require 4.0.10 when 4.0.0 should suffice?

**EDIT 2:**

I created a new blank app and a similar problem occured but this time with no library dependencies and this time I tried to use 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' and I got the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in App1.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Primitives, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I'm running OS build **10.0.10586.0** but I'm starting to consider that there is something wrong with my device.

Comment: Does it work if you use the nuget package?

Comment: No, but it's a different error (that i've fixed, thats why i have to use my modified source).

Comment: Have you tried to test with emulator? What's the result? Actually, in UWP app, it uses .net core but not the general .net framework. And the version should be 4.6.xxxxx.x . Since it's trying to find the wrong versions, I think it is possible that the .net core assemblies are not successfully downloaded/installed into your project. Generally, after build the UWP solution, we can find the .net core assemblies in bin folder(like <project path>\bin\x86\Debug). Take the System.Net.Primitives as an example, you will find it there and get the 4.6.xxxxx.x version.

Comment: If the assemblies are not there, there must be something wrong with nuget to retrieve the package.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my visual studio installation was messed up... so I did a complete reinstallation of the entire OS, and now it (and my apps) works properly.

Thank you Alan Yao for your input!